# How will a transformer react to a PWM signal?

Tags: transformer, pwm

I want to power a 6.3 volt transformer with 115 AC. I will be pulse width modulating the 115 volt AC signal using a PWM controller.

Will the transformer react instantly to the reduced duty cycle, or will it "see" a reduced voltage as its input?

My goal is to use the 6.3 volt signal to power a resistive heater of large thermal mass which will act as a thermal capacitor to smooth the final heat energy output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m very interested in how you’ll be pulse width modulating the 115V AC input, can you please add some more details there?

Comment: The transformer will need to accomodate the lowest frequency, e.g. if you have a 50 kHz PWM modulated by a 50 Hz sine then the transformer will need to be dimensioned for the 50 Hz case, not 50 kHz. Don't forget that there is a derivative involved, whose frequency response is similar to a highpass, and a coupling effect, which creates a high frequency pole -- resulting in a bandpass response.

Comment: Normally you’d use phase control to vary the power input. Just like a light dimmer. Phase control is a form of pwm but don’t confuse them.  I use a cheapy ‘power controller’ from ebays to vary my lathe motor speed. It uses phase control. Assuming you have a resistive load on the secondary, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the transformer it will react pretty fast on you PWM source. You should take care that you don't introduce an average DC value as this will slowly saturate the core of the transformer and then it won't work really well. SMPS transformers usually have an additional winding they use to desaturate the core with.

Figuring the exact response of the transformer will be tricky and you will need to perform the short and open circuit tests at a coulple of frequencies.